# How do I make .py files executable by default on mac OS?

Tags: python, macos

I know that you can do "chmod +x filename.py" to make the file executable on mac but is there a way I can change some setting so that happens by default when I create a filename with .py extension?

Comment: See this stackoverflow which covers the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564320/how-to-make-python-script-executable-on-osx

Comment: Thank you SteveB but that thread's answer still asks you to run chmod +x command where as I want to find a way so that MacOS automatically assigns the +x bit to any *.py file right from creation.

Comment: You can have the whole folder to be executable.

Comment: @user1767754 Thank you. That's a great workaround. I know windows has a way to set default but this takes care of my problem for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how sensible an idea this is, but you can achieve it using a *"filesystem watcher"* such as `fswatch` (the macOS equivalent of Linux's `inotifywait`).

So, you can use [homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install `fswatch` like this:

```
brew install fswatch
```

Then, say you wanted to monitor all filesystem events under your `HOME` directory that pertain to Python files and involve file creation, you could run:

```
fswatch -0 -E --event Created -e ".*" -i ".py$" $HOME | xargs -0 -n1 chmod +x
```

You won't see anything, but as soon as you create a file ending in `.py`, it will run `chmod +x` on that file to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

using Automator, create an application that runs a shell script that runs python, and set the default application for opening .py files.