# Run Apple Script before application start?

Tags: macos, applescript, mount, automator

Was wondering if there is any way to run a small piece of apple script when I launch an application on OS X? 
I have a hard-drive which need to be mounted in order for the app to run right. I did this apple script already:

```
on run
try

    do shell script "diskutil mountDisk disk2"

    delay 3
    tell application "Application"
        run
    end tell

on error
    tell application "Application"
        quit
    end tell
    set question to display dialog "Error." buttons {"OK"}
    set answer to button returned of question
    if answer is equal to "OK" then
        close
    end if

end try
end run
```

But even tho this works great and the hard-drive spins up before the app starts. 
I would like to add the `diskutil mountDisk disk2` and delay directly in front of the real application when its starting so I can double click files for that app say in my downloads folder. Which will run the script before it opens the clicked file in the app. So I wont have to start the application with another application each time i download a new file for it. Is this even possible?

Comment: You could maybe run `fswatch` (which can be installed with **homebrew**) and monitor the executable binary for your app to see when it is opened and then run your `diskutil mountDisk` command... and hope you get there in time. Something related here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978505/2836621

Comment: work around I use is to create the applescript which runs diskutil first, then open the application. I remove the app icon from the doc and replace it by the icon of the script. I always click on this script to start both script and application.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly:

It's **not** possible unless the application itself supports some *inhook* and *outhook* functionality.