# How can I get pyinstaller to work on Mac?

Tags: macos, pyinstaller

I'm trying to have an executable file for my python program on Mac and I have done so using pyinstaller with the following command --> pyinstaller --windowed 'program name'.py
I got files and stuff but when I run the program it opens for less than a second then closes. Am I supposed to do something else?

Comment: Try pyinstaller filename.py, or pyinstaller -F filename.py

Comment: I tried both methods, but it gives me a Unix executable file inside dict, which I believe can't be opened using Mac. When I use --windowed I do get a program which seems to be executable but It doesn't does anything when I open it.

Comment: ok, so your console screen shows something or it just fully empty?

Comment: Try these [link1](https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra/1164713) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564320/how-to-make-python-script-executable-on-osx)[link3](http://skillfulness.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-run-python-script-from-mac-os-x.html) and do tell me your problem is solved or not.