# How do I convert a .py into a standalone application/exe and run it in the background?

Tags: python, macos-catalina

- Operating System: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Python Version: 3.10.1 (latest)

I would like to convert a .py file into a standalone app bundle for macOS and an executable for Windows. Said .py runs within my system terminal, and when I create my executable/app bundle, I want the terminal to run in the background.

Currently, I run my .py file in a virtual environment with the required modules, operating on Python 3.10.1. I do so by activating the environment and running:

```
python /main.py
```

in my file directory within my terminal. This runs my script just fine within the terminal, but this is not the final product I want and I'm having trouble converting it into an app bundle.

I have tried using py2app to achieve this, first running:

```
py2applet --make-setup main.py
```

in my program directory in order to make the setup file, then by running:

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

to make the Python alias. The alias runs fine when I put click on the unix executable within Contents>MacOS>myprogram.py, but it doesn't run at all when I delete my dist and build folders and remake them without the alias. It says "Launch Error: See the py2app wesbite for debugging launch issues". I visited the website but am still unsure what to do about this.

So to summarize, I have two goals:

1. Create sucessful standalone app bundles and executables for my script without recieving a launch error.
2. Run said executable or app bundle in the background where the terminal is not visible if I manage to complete goal one sucessfully.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't think that `macOS` can run an `exe` file (at least not [easily](https://cleanmymac.com/blog/run-exe-files-mac)) (although they asked for Windows too)

Comment: @Matiiss good point. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36564320/6045800) could be relevant

Answer (score 1):

You can create standalone windows executables with pyinstaller. You can install it with pip.

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

After installation, navigate to the directory that your .py file is in. Then simply execute this command in Terminal:

```
pyinstaller yourfile.py
```

Comment: The question is about MacOS...