# How can one start a Python package from a mac's graphical user interface?

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, python-3.6

This question was [asked once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793391/easy-way-to-launch-python-scripts-with-the-mouse-in-os-x), but seeing as that discussion was five years ago and I've tried some of its recommendations without success, I'm asking it again, albeit in a slightly different context.

I installed the [topydo Python app](https://github.com/bram85/topydo), and it runs fine from the terminal (i.e., at the command prompt, entering "topydo," "topydo prompt," or "topydo columns" all work as they should). But then I tried two solutions suggested on the previously cited thread (Automator and AppleScript solutions), and neither of them worked. It appears that the OS can't find the topydo executable. I even tried using an absolute path, /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/topydo,
but had no luck.

Any ideas how to create a clickable icon that will launch topydo from the Mac's GUI? (This is on OS X 10.10.5, Yosemite.) Having to open a terminal window every time I want to run the program is a real drag.

(BTW, while nosing around to deal with this, I noticed that /Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Versions has a subdirectory named "Current," but "Current" doesn't have the newly installed topydo executable. Instead, topydo is in the 3.6 subdirectory. I assume this is because the Mac ships with Python 2.7, which is used by the system. Assuming the "Current" directory is defined via a symlink, would redefining it to point to the 3.6 subdirectory instead of to the 2.7 subdirectory be likely to cause a problem?

Comment: What happens if you type `which topydo` in Terminal?

Comment: What happens if you run `open -a Terminal.app "$(which topydo)"` ?

Comment: What happens when you google for more recent solutions? This one, for example, is younger than 5 yrs: http://naelshiab.com/tutorial-how-to-automatically-run-your-scripts-on-your-computer/

Comment: which topydo -- yields the path to what appears to be the topydo python script

Comment: open -a Terminal.app _etc._ runs the app, without any CLI options